# block all outgoing traffic from server, allowing limited ips using iptables

Tags: iptables

Can some one help me in the below requirement using `iptables`:

- Block all the traffic, allowing only said traffic.

I tried below rule by googling,

```
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

which drops every thing, I could also see few rules which will allow only certain ips

I am not able to get the `!` expression clearly.

Answer (score 0):

not sure I understood what is your question about, the (!) operator means  negation, for example --src !10.1.1.1 matches all the traffic which has a source IP something DIFFERENT from that, what do you mean for 'allowing said traffic ?"